# OOM error because GC is not cleaning up the old custom view

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-custom-view

I have a custom view I created which takes up a fair amount of memory. The fragment that this view is attached to is recreated by a fragmentViewPager when the user goes to that page. The problem I am running into is that after 7 or 8 recreations I get an OutOfMemoryError. I know it is this view because when I remove it the OOM completely stops. My gander is that something is still holding a reference to the old view which causes the GC to skip it. To try and fix this I created a close method in the custom view that de-reference everything inside the custom view class, this did not seem to help either.

[image]

Each hump is when the view is recreated. trying to cause a GC by the button in the debugger doesn't cause any of the memory to be cleaned up.

```
public void close(){

    bitmapFace  .recycle();


    largeLinePaint      = null;
    smallLinePaint      = null;
    dialIndicatorPaint  = null;
    solidSeekPaint      = null;
    textPaint           = null;
    dialShader          = null;
    dialPaint           = null;
    dial                = null;
    bitmapFace          = null;
    listener            = null;
    dialFacePoints      = null;
    matrix              = null;
    dialPath            = null;
    leftTrianglePath    = null;
    rightTrianglePath   = null;
}
```

This is the method that I use to dereference everything; it is called from the onPause of the fragment. I cannot think of any other place that the view is being referenced from. Does anyone know why the GC is not cleaning up the memory.

Here is the heap dumb, I see that most all of the memory is in these two methods but I don't know why the memory is not getting cleaned up from the previous view.

[image]

```
private void initializeDial(){
    float textPoint         = .91f;
    float largeLineEnd      = .9f;
    float largeLineStart    = .8f;
    float smallLineEnd      = .86f;
    float smallLineStart    = .8f;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)radius*2, (int)radius*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    int station = 87;
    for(int x = 0; x < 106; x++){
        if(x % 5 == 0){ //big line

            canvas.drawLine(
                    (float) (radius),
                    (float) (radius - (largeLineStart * radius)),
                    (float) (radius),
                    (float) (radius - (largeLineEnd * radius)),
                    largeLinePaint);

            canvas.drawText(
                    Integer.toString(station),
                    radius,
                    radius - (textPoint * radius),
                    textPaint);

            station = station + 1;

        }else { //small line
            canvas.drawLine(
                    (float)(radius),
                    (float)(radius - (smallLineStart*radius)),
                    (float)(radius),
                    (float)(radius - (smallLineEnd*radius)),
                    smallLinePaint);
        }
        canvas.rotate(3,radius,radius);
    }
    canvas.rotate(-3 * 106, radius,radius);

    dialShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    dialWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    canvas.setBitmap(null);
    canvas = null;
}
```

I use this bitmap on the draw canvas so I have to keep it (until the view is destroyed.

```
private void createFaceBitmap(){
    bitmapFace = Bitmap.createBitmap(contentWidth,contentHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapFace);


    canvas.drawLine(
            dialFacePoints[0],
            dialFacePoints[1],
            dialFacePoints[2],
            dialFacePoints[3],
            dialIndicatorPaint);

    canvas.drawLine(
            dialFacePoints[4],
            dialFacePoints[5],
            dialFacePoints[6],
            dialFacePoints[7],
            smallLinePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(
            dialFacePoints[8],
            dialFacePoints[9],
            dialFacePoints[10],
            dialFacePoints[11],
            smallLinePaint);


    canvas.drawPath(leftTrianglePath, solidSeekPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(rightTrianglePath, solidSeekPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(leftTrianglePath, largeLinePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(rightTrianglePath, largeLinePaint);

    canvas.setBitmap(null);
}
```

onDraw

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapFace,0,0,null);

    matrix.setRotate(-rotation, radius, radius);
    matrix.postTranslate(dialFacePoints[12], (float) ((getHeight() / 2) - ((.25 * radius) / 2)));
    dialShader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    dialPaint.setShader(dialShader);


    canvas.drawPath(dialPath, dialPaint);
}
```

Comment: Inspect the heap dump. Hard to say without your complete code.

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to your context anywhere? That is one of the most common memory leeks in Android.

Comment: I added the places where all the memory is getting used. I don't think I am keeping a context, I've completely gutted both the activity and the fragment of everything except this view and it still has this memory leak

Comment: I figured out where it is coming from I just don't know how to fix it. It is coming from 
    dialPaint.setShader(dialShader);